# Move view up when keyboard shows, for textfield in a stackview

Tags: ios, swift

I have a scenario were i move the view up when the keyboard appears, this scenario works fine however as soon as i start typing the view goes back to its original position. Something to note is that the textfield is in a stackview.

My question is that is there a way i can stop the view from going back to its original position when textEditing begins.

This is my code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

 var isScroll = false


@objc func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    mainView.frame.origin.y = -100
}
@objc func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    mainView.frame.origin.y = 0
}
```

Comment: First of all, is there any reason you're not using Auto Layout? Secondly you shouldn't change your Y value like this.

Comment: Can you show your text field delegates?

Comment: I would suggest using https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager it manages UITextField very easily

Comment: i am using autolayouts , i have a custom component with a number of controls inside it and i show them on a placeholder view which is on the viewController

Comment: the textfield is in this nib "customview"

Comment: did you change mainView frame in `textField` begin editing method?

Comment: i cannot do that because the code for textField begin editing is abstracted in the custom component

Comment: update your question with screens, Basic look screen, and the screen with issue so others can guide you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a scrollview as your base view and inside this add your contentview then

```
func keyboardShown(_ notification: Notification){

    var userInfo        = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize    = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    let contentInsets   = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, (keyboardSize!.height + 40), 0.0)
    self.mainScrollView.contentInset            = contentInsets
    self.mainScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets   = contentInsets



    // **-- Scroll when keyboard shows up
    let aRect           = self.view.frame
    self.mainScrollView.contentSize = aRect.size

    /* if((self.activeTextField) != nil)
     {
     self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(self.activeTextField!.frame, animated: true)
     }*/

}

func keyboardHidden(_ notification: Notification) {

    let contentInsets   = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    self.mainScrollView.contentInset            = contentInsets
    self.mainScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets   = contentInsets

    // **-- Scroll when keyboard shows up
    self.mainScrollView.contentSize = self.containerView.frame.size
}
```

Comment: could you please explain this code :self.mainScrollView.contentSize = aRect.size   and self.mainScrollView.contentSize = self.containerView.frame.size

Comment: im having a problem were there is a delay in the scrollview when the keyboard shows

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion to use this [library](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) else you can manage the whole UI into the UITableview so no need to manage keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide method in that controller.

Comment: libraries are not an option

Comment: Your answer is already pasted in question comment. I would like to suggest you to put this as comment not as an answer.

Comment: Yes, @Kuldeep I have seen after posting my answer.

Comment: @Erent You can use UITableview and in that add your UITextfield into the cell so automatically UITextfield will move whenever keyboard will be appeared.

Comment: So i am consuming a custom component which has other controls , it will be much difficult to remove the stackview and put a tableview.

Comment: Can you please show me an exact UI though I am guiding you in a better way.
like the hierarchy of UI.